# Attribute.IsDefined is not available in portable class library

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes, portable-class-library

Why I do not have access to `Attribute.IsDefined()` in a portable class library? How could I use this method in `PCL`? In a class library the following code works perfect but in a pcl it says there is no method there.

```
if (Attribute.IsDefined(item, typeof(Title))) ...
```

`Title` is an attribute. Is it possible to solve this problem by adding a reference or something to the project?

Comment: Always mention the targets you selected for your PCL project, they matter.  Reflection is in general a problem, not very portable to WinRT targets.  You probably need to use the TypeInfo class instead.

Comment: Of what type is `item`?